# Validation giving error in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-3.3.x, extensions

I am using Joomla 2.5 user registration form. I added manually one more fields for user phone number, and I am doing server side validation.

Code is : registration.xml

```
<form
      addrulepath="/administrator/components/com_user/models/rules"
      >
     <field 
     name="pnumber" 
     type="text"
    description="Enter your valid Number"
    label="Phone number:"
    required="true"
    size="30"
    hint="EX:080-12345678"
    class="inputbox validate-mobile"

    />
```

and I have created validation file in administrator\components\com_users\models\rules\mobile.php

code is :

```
    <?php


     defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

     jimport('joomla.form.formrule');


     class JFormRuleMobile extends JFormRule
     {


     public function mobile(& $element, $value, $group = null, & $input = null, & $form = null)
     {
     return preg_match("/^\+{0,1}[0-9]{6,14}$/",$value);
     }
  }

  ?>
```

When I submit the form "Validation Rule missing: mobile" error is coming. What is the problem?

Comment: Is this a completely manual field you have added or are you doing it through the Joomla profile plugin?

Comment: manual field only . adding in registration.xml file

Comment: @Lodder any solution ?

Comment: please check i have modified my question .

Answer (score 1):

Ufff ......  I got the Answer .

I just used joomla inbuilt rule called "tel"

problem solved . thank you every one  :)

Comment: Ahh fair enough. Would have recommended this, but thought you required something more specific. Don't forget to accept your answer when you can ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Add `validate="mobile"` to your `<field>` in the XML file

Then change the mobile.php to the following:

```
<?php

defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;
jimport('joomla.form.formrule');

class JFormRuleMobile extends JFormRule {

    protected $regex = '^\+?\d{6,14}$';

}
```

Let me know what the outcome of this is.

Comment: same error  (Validation Rule missing: mobile)

Comment: and i have one doubt . i am giving validation in registration.xml (components\com_users\models\forms). this path is correct ?

Comment: @manikantakjgowda - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28088929/1362108